# Construct continuous martingales that are close to constants

Tags: martingales

Let $\mu_0,\mu_1$ be probability measures on $\mathbb R$ that are of finite second moment and increasing in convex order, i.e.

$$\int_\mathbb R f(x)\mu_0(dx) \le \int_\mathbb R f(x)\mu_1(dx)$$

holds for all convex functions $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. Denote by $W_2$ the Wasserstein metric. My question is as follows : if $\mu_0 \approx \mu_1$ under $W_2$, can we construct a continuous martingale $(X_t)_{0\le t\le 1}$ such that ${\rm Law }(X_t)=\mu_t$ for $t=0,1$ and

$$ \mathbb E\big[\sup_{0\le s\le t\le 1}|X_s-X_t|^2\big]\approx 0.$$

Formulated mathematically, does there exist some continuous function $r:\mathbb R_+ \to\mathbb R_+$ with $r(0)=0$ such that the above martingale satisfies

$$\mathbb E\big[\sup_{0\le s\le t\le 1}|X_s-X_t|^2\big]\le r\big(W_2(\mu_0,\mu_1)\big)?$$